# ElasticSearch : Https not working inside container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2.0

I have implemented ElasticSearch for one of my application (Net core 2.1).

From locally or deployed to any normal server (Inside our company) everything works fine. Logs are successfully logged.

The problem starts when I deploy my application inside the Docker container. It throws an exception. Based on my findings, it's because ElasticSearch Url is https and have a certificate with it.

Docker File :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.1
WORKDIR /app
ADD test/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/linux-x64/* /app/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.dll", "--console"]
```

Compose File :

```
services: 

  app: # service definition: Mandatory - PRINCIPLE # 2

    # Mandatory - PRINCIPLE # 9 - images in DTR to use the assigned org name for the project context.
    # project org name is 'om-cockpit'
    image: __IMAGE__


    # Mandatory - PRINCIPLE # 5
    deploy:
        replicas: 1
        restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure

        # Mandatory - PRINCIPLE # 3
        resources:
            limits:
                #cpus: "0.1" # Not supported on Windows platforms
                memory: 256M

        # Mandatory - PRINCIPLE # 4
        placement:
            constraints:
                - node.role == worker
                - node.labels.test== true

        # Mandatory - PRINCIPLE # 11
        labels:
            com.docker.ucp.access.label: /Shared/test/ops

    environment:
    # We'll use the entrypoint and a command param to specify which ports the app should to listen on
    #    ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:8080 # This env var is overridden by hosting.json, so use the --urls cmd param
        ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Dev
        ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:8110

    # Override/define the entrypoint for the image
    entrypoint: /app/O.WP.Work --console --urls=http://*:8110 --environment=Dev


    # Defines port mapping on the host to the container port
    # Service ports should be exposed only if it's necessary to reach the application from external resource
    # PRINCIPLE # 7
    ports:
        #   - "8050:8050"
        - target: 8110 #container
          published: 12111 #public port
          protocol: tcp
```

I am getting this exception

```
Elastic Search : 2019-07-07T08:02:32.3113052Z Caught exception while preforming bulk operation to Elasticsearch: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)

   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)

   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)

   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()

   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)

   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData) in c:\Projects\elastic\net-master\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpConnection-CoreFx.cs:line 73

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.HandleElasticsearchClientException(RequestData data, Exception clientException, IElasticsearchResponse response) in c:\Projects\elastic\net-master\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Transport\Transport.cs:line 196

   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.FinalizeResponse[TResponse](RequestData requestData, IRequestPipeline pipeline, List`1 seenExceptions, TResponse response) in c:\Projects\elastic\net-master\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Transport\Transport.cs:line 180

   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters) in c:\Projects\elastic\net-master\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Transport\Transport.cs:line 97

   at Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSink.EmitBatchChecked[T](IEnumerable`1 events)

   at Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSink.EmitBatch(IEnumerable`1 events)
```

Comment: Is your elasticsearch server using self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes it is using self-signed